# lerna canary how to pump up version correctly

Tags: lerna

I'm trying to do `lerna publish --canary`

I'm seeing the "number" after "alpha" is not bumped up (look at the 2nd and 3rd are both `alpha.1` )

`0.1.3-alpha.0+34fcd0a`

`0.1.3-alpha.1+d9a9ecb`

`0.1.3-alpha.1+ezacf1c`

How can I make sure that everytime the canary publish can bump up the number after `alpha` ?

`0.1.3-alpha.0+{someSHA}`

`0.1.3-alpha.1+{someSHA}`

`0.1.3-alpha.2+{someSHA}`

`0.1.3-alpha.3+{someSHA}`

Answer (score 0):

I wound up having to fetch more git history
e.g. in github actions:

```
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
```

The version number comes from `git describe`, which counts the amount of commits from the last tag.